# Vim: Make function with count only operate once

Tags: vim

I have this function:

```
function Test()
    echom "call " . v:count
endfunction
nnoremap a :call Test()<cr>
```

If I type, let's say `4a`, it will print out

> call 4 
>   call 4 
>   call 4 
>   call 4

However, I want it only to be executed once, when I use a count. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should read - What should I do when someone answers my question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `<C-U>` before calling the function.

```
function Test()
   echom "call " . v:count
endfunction
nnoremap a :<C-U>call Test()<cr>
```

`<C-U>` removes all the characters before the cursor on command line. From help:

```
                                                        c_CTRL-U
CTRL-U          Remove all characters between the cursor position and
                the beginning of the line.  Previous versions of vim
                deleted all characters on the line.  If that is the
                preferred behavior, add the following to your .vimrc:
                        :cnoremap <C-U> <C-E><C-U>
```